# How to obtain a public static IP for windows azure

Tags: azure

I created a vm on azure which runs a web application. 
The vm got created with azure arm.
This application communicates with other web services and they authenticate the ip of the request.
Therefore I need a static IP which won't change.
Furthermore I want to set a dns entry to the web server, also I need here the static IP.
How can this be achieved on azure?

Comment: This question should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

For Azure Resource Manager you have to create a load balancer, assign a static VIP to the load balancer, create the rules, create the NICs and then bind the rules and NICs together:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-arm-powershell/

**Legacy API Instructions**
The old way but much easier. You have to create a static IP and then assign it to your cloud service where the VM resides.

New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName "MyReservedIP" –Location "AzureRegionName"

New-AzureVM -ServiceName "NewServiceName" -ReservedIPName "MyReservedIP" -Location "AzureRegionName"

Full example [here](http://www.francoisdelport.com/2015/10/how-to-assign-a-public-static-ip-address-in-azure/).

Your cloud service will keep the DNS assigned to it until you destroy it. If you want to use your own domain name you have to create a CNAME that points to your Azure URL or an A record that points to the static IP you assigned above with your domain registrar.

The Public IP address you assign in the portal is the PIP and cannot be static. I could not find a way to create a load balancer in the preview portal.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Does this also work in the new azure portal or via azure cli in arm mode?

Comment: I don't think you can do it from the portal, I use Azure PowerShell and it looks like you can do it from Azure CLI using arm but I didn't use CLI yet myself.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-static-private-ip-classic-cli/

Comment: hm, that's the doc for a private ip

Comment: These are instructions for working with the legacy API, not ARM. And Cloud Services don't exist in the ARM world.

Comment: @DavidMakogon that's interesting, can you point to the doc where they connect the legacy api?

Comment: @dc10 - not sure I understand the question. I'm just stating that there are two API's to manage azure - legacy and Azure Resource Manager (ARM). You said you used ARM to deploy a VM, meaning you must use ARM-based CLI commands to modify its IP address. Or you can do it via the portal. But this is a ServerFault question, not a programming question. It should be asked there.

Comment: @DavidMakogon But how can I do it via portal? In the docs is says a static public ip can only be assigned to a load balander and not a vm. Because when i try to assign a public ip in the portal to a vm it is not possible since the list shows a disabled list of public IP's (this confirms that is not possible at vm level). So the question in general remains unsolved to me. How can i assign a static public IP to a newly provisioned VM which got created via arm?  Regarding where the question should be posted, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/forums/